# Wicket DropDownChoice setting model value

Tags: drop-down-menu, wicket, wicket-1.5

I have a table (Dataview) with content from a database, where each row/object has an "edit" button. When I try to edit the object, the DropDownChoice-value (in a form) is not correctly updated (even though it is correct in the database). The value that gets set in the DDC is the first item in the (sorted) list "placeList", where I obviously want the correct value from my object (event.getPlace().getName()).

Here is the code (wicket 1.5):

```
    List<Place> placesList = UtGuidenApplication.getInstance().getUgpService().getAllPlaces();
    Collections.sort(placesList);

    DropDownChoice<Place> selectablePlaceField = new DropDownChoice<Place>("Sted", new PropertyModel<Place>(event, "eventPlace.name"),
            placesList, new ChoiceRenderer<Place>("name"));
    utguidenEventForm.add(selectablePlaceField);
```

Anybody?

Cheers,
Terje Eithun,
Norway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have an error in your model. You've written `new PropertyModel<Place>(event, "eventPlace.name")` which contains the name of your event as model, but the list of choices contains places. I think using `new PropertyModel<Place>(event, "eventPlace")` should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Actually I have tried what you suggested, but the result was the same (ddc-value is the first in thesorted list).

Comment: @TerjeEithun Hmm, maybe there are other issues? Is the event place on your event `null`? Is there a typo in the property? In these cases I think the first choice is shown as well. Maybe you can also have a look at [this page](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/dropdownchoice.html). I'm personally using a lot of drop down choices and the approach there, as well as in my answer, works fine for me.

Comment: You probably is right, I just can`t spot the error. This is the relevant markup:`<p>
    <label>Sted: *</label> <select wicket:id="Sted"></select>
   </p>`

Comment: Ah, I have another idea. Wicket uses the equals() method to match the choices with the current value. Does your `Place` class implement equals()?

Comment: Bingo! There it was. I implemented equals(), and it worked right away. Thank you very much. I was about to tear my hair off. :)

Comment: @r3nj1 I spent 2 hours trying to figure out why the hell the gui component for the DropDown was not updating until I found this question... thanks a lot guys, you made my day! :)